# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery', but this dictionary requires a model item of type B

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I been stuck in a situation and I tried finding the solution for it on net but was not successful. I am new to MVC with Entity Framework, and it is throwing the exception when i try to run the application:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[UnRelatedEntity.Models.t_AbortReason,UnRelatedEntity.Models.t_Activity]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'UnRelatedEntity.Models.MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1'

I am using an Entity as a model which fetches **Data from two tables** seperately which do not have relation among them.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1 ent = new MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1();
    var result = from foo in ent.t_AbortReason
                 from bar in ent.t_Activity
                 where foo.AbortReasonCategoryId != null && bar.ActivityId != null
                 select new { Foo = foo, Bar = bar };
    return View(result);
}
```

**View**

```
@model UnRelatedEntity.Models.MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1
```

In the view I am just writing the above line i mean i am just inheriting the Model, nothing else but still I am confused about how to type cast model w.r.t model, but I am helpless.

Can anyone please provide me help on this, but please keep in mind i am using two unrelated tables in my model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Shad points out, the reason you are getting this error is simply because you are passing a different type of data into the view than what you have said you would.

To solve this, you need a model that you can pass into your view that holds the data you need:

```
public class FooBarModel
{
    public AbortReason Foo { get;set;}
    public Activity Bar { get;set;}
}
```

Then, in your `Index` method, do something like this:

```
using(MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1 ent = new MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1())
{
    var result = from foo in ent.t_AbortReason
                 from bar in ent.t_Activity
                 where foo.AbortReasonCategoryId != null && bar.ActivityId != null
                 select new FooBarModel() { Foo = foo, Bar = bar };
    return View(result);
}
```

And in your view, set the model type:

```
@model IEnumerable<my.namespace.FooBarModel>
```

Comment: Nick, so i have to make a new class to encapsulate **AbortReason** and **Activity**

Comment: That's right. Keep in mind its namespace, you'll need that to set the model type in the view. Maybe just create the class in your Models folder.

Comment: My use of `AbortReason` and `Activity` was really just inferred from your query - you could just replace `AbortReason` and `Activity` with whatever the actual types are.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me, but in the end, for some reason, EF 6 seemed to interpret this as a query:

```
var patient = db.Patient.Where(p => p.ID == id);
```

while this returned the Model I needed and works for me:

```
var patient = db.Patient.Where(p => p.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That worked for me. Actually, I had an IEnumerable declared on my ViewModel but I was passing an IQueryable (your first example). Justing setting my query with ToList() (similar to your second example) solved the problem.

Comment: You should use my method instead, IEnum creates a new stack of memory use each time you add something to it, while EF6 also does it, so let EF6 handle that part, otherwise its a double job for your application

Comment: I didn't understood what you said. I'm using your method. In your first line of code, your var is an IQueryable (and that's why EF interpret it as a query) while in your second line, your var is an object<Patient>. The only difference between our code is that you get only one Patient while I get an IEnumerable (List) of Patients. Both codes creates a new stack of memory.

Comment: That is true, thnx for teaching me something new, the first one might have been fixed by Microsogt in EF now

Answer (score 1):

Your view expects model of type `UnRelatedEntity.Models.MobilePhoneXchangeEntities1`, but you pass `result` object to it. `result` is a database query, which you have described in controller action. So, you get expected error - type mismatch.

To fix this you should create type for your query items. Very simple example:

```
public class ResultItem
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

After that modify select statement in your query:

```
select new ResultItem { Foo = foo, Bar = bar };
```

and in the end, change model type of the view to `IEnumerable<ResultItem>`, because query will return collection of result items.

Comment: Thanks Shad... Thanks for your time and help and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Person.Models.Location', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Person.Models.LoginModel'.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new object or instance with the correct type

@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new MVCTest.Models.LoginViewModel())

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an exception into your database.

To see the exact error(s), you should have something like this:

```
private DbCtx db = new DbCtx();

try
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    base.Seed(ctx);
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    string errorMessages = string.Join("; ", ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.PropertyName + ": " + x.ErrorMessage));
    throw new DbEntityValidationException(errorMessages);
}
```

where `DbCtx` is a your database building class.