# Display the sum of the orders of the month in chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, charts

I don`t know how to display, at the beginning the sum of the orders of the month in the table in the asp.net MVC. 
My data in table Order look like:

> DateCreated | TotalPrice 
>     2017-02-06  |  400 
>     2017-02-06  |  300 
>     2017-03-06  | 100 
>     2017-03-06 | 50

And I want to get mountly sum of TotalPrice, like this:

> DateCreated | TotalPrice 
>     2017-02     | 700 
>     2017-03     | 150

My model class Order:

```
public int orderId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public string comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public OrderState orderState { get; set; }
    public decimal totalPrice { get; set; }

    public List<OrderIteam> OrderIteams { get; set; }
```

I try to write something like this to display the sum of the orders of the month in the table :

```
public ActionResult ListOrder()
{
    var result =
        from s in db.Orders
        group s by new { date = new DateTime(s.dateCreated.Year, s.dateCreated.Month, 1) } into g
        select new
        {
            dateCreated = g.Key.date,
            sumTotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice)
        };
    return View(result);
}
```

[My view looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9O5o.png)

I am getting the error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.DateTime,System.Decimal]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sklep_Internetowy.Models.Order]'.

At the end I would like to show that the sum of the orders of a given month as the chart below:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4KqH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the LINQ query below returns `DbQuery` instance with anonymous type instead of `IEnumerable` collection:

```
var result = from s in db.Orders
             group s by new { date = new DateTime(s.dateCreated.Year, s.dateCreated.Month, 1) } into g
             select new
             {
                 dateCreated = g.Key.date,
                 sumTotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice)
             }; // returns System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<AnonymousTypeN>
```

The reason behind thrown `InvalidOperationException` here is simply because a different type of data has been passed into the view which requires `IEnumerable<Sklep_Internetowy.Models.Order>`.

Try change return type to `Order` instead using anonymous type one:

```
var result = from s in db.Orders
             group s by new { date = new DateTime(s.dateCreated.Year, s.dateCreated.Month, 1) } into g
             select new Order // return Sklep_Internetowy.Models.Order here
             {
                 dateCreated = g.Key.date,
                 sumTotalPrice = g.Sum(x => x.totalPrice)
             };
```

At this point, the return type of LINQ query above becomes `IQueryable<Sklep_Internetowy.Models.Order>` which implements `IEnumerable`, hence it doesn't require conversion (but you may still need to [use collection aggregate methods to execute it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061970/6378815), e.g. `ToList()`).

Related issues:

[The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery', but this dictionary requires a model item of type B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110590/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-data-entity-infrast)

[The model item passed into the dictionary is 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`, but requires 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061385/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-system-data-entity-infrastructure?rq=1)

Comment: I used your code and now I have an error: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Have you use another methods before returning view after the query statement? `NotSupportedException` indicates other problem occurs after the query has executed, hence include line of code which throwing exception. If you using `highcharts.js`, also look at this: https://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tetsuya Yamamoto. Constructs a date with parameters. I guess because I have this error but I do not know how else to save.

Comment: You can show the data model class structure and related query processing code which triggering `NotSupportedException`. The modified query above should work if model class constructors are thoroughly examined.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsuya Yamamoto. My code now works correctly.